# Cargo unable to set the system properties values during bean injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cargo, maven-cargo

**What I am trying to do?**
- For testing, I want to set `serverKey` and `validity` for my application and want cargo to inject into TokenUtils, so these values are available when the application is loaded

**What I have tried?**
I am using `JBoss` as Container and the relevant code is

```
@Stateless
public class TokenUtils {

    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "X-BB-AUTH";
    public static final String BB_AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY = "auth.key";
    public static final String BB_AUTH_VALIDITY = "auth.validity";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":");

    private String serverPrivateKey;
    private long validity;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenUtils.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public TokenUtils() {
    }

    public TokenUtils(@Nonnull @Configuration(BB_AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY) final String serverPrivateKey,
                      @Configuration(BB_AUTH_VALIDITY) final long validity) {
        this.serverPrivateKey = serverPrivateKey;
        this.validity = validity;

        LOGGER.info("serverPrivateKey:" + serverPrivateKey);
        LOGGER.info("validity:" + validity);
    }
}
```

Also, I have `META-INF/beans.xml` in the `src/main/resources` of the same package where `TokenUtils` is created, so bean instantiation is not a problem I guess

I want the values to be injected when cargo instantiate the bean, so I set the values in `pom.xml` as

```
<container>
  <systemProperties>
    <auth.key>secure</auth.key>
    <auth.validity>720000</auth.validity>
  </systemProperties>
</container>
```

When I start cargo, I see the following happening

```
INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 06:07:08,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named TokenUtils in deployment unit deployment "market.war" are as follows:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/market/TokenUtils!com.org.proj.service.authentication.TokenUtils
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/market/TokenUtils!com.com.proj.service.authentication.TokenUtils
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/TokenUtils!com.com.proj.service.authentication.TokenUtils
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/market/TokenUtils
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/market/TokenUtils
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/TokenUtils
```

**Problem?**
- But the values are `serverPrivateKey=null` and `validity=0`
- Moreover, during bean instantiation, I should be able to see `LOGGER.info` values, but I can't find them in logs

What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the fault. I was not using `@Inject` in my `TokenUtils` constructor. The following change fixed it

```
@Inject
public TokenUtils(@Nonnull @Configuration(BB_AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY) final String serverPrivateKey,
                      @Configuration(BB_AUTH_VALIDITY) final long validity) {
        this.serverPrivateKey = serverPrivateKey;
        this.validity = validity;

        LOGGER.info("serverPrivateKey:" + serverPrivateKey);
        LOGGER.info("validity:" + validity);
    }
```

With that I could see values in logs as following

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 06:39:30,042 INFO  [com.org.proj.commons.cdi.config.ConfigurationProvider] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-1) getProperty(auth.key) is secure
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 06:39:30,043 INFO  [com.org.proj.commons.cdi.config.ConfigurationProvider] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-1) getProperty(auth.validity) is 720000
```